# Background Service thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service, background

I have started a Background Service.
I am aware that this is started on the main thread and so I have create new thread/runnable within the Background class.

I seem to be spending a lot of time managing how to prevent the thread and background service continuing, which is leading me to believe I may be better off using an Intent Service and run it at the specified timer interval from my main activity.
The background service is currently performing a network operation once every 10 seconds and then sleeping.
It also uses a broadcast intent to send info to any listening activities.

My question is: When I kill the Background Service (either by stopSelf(); or if I use a bound service the 'unbind' command, will this also kill the created thread without me explicitly calling thread.interrupt?
Is this an efficient way of utilising a background service given the added need for threading?

Comment: yeah you should be using an IntentService if you want to start then stop the service after its done

Comment: thanks for the reply - does this mean I'll have to use a timer of some kind to fire this intent. The issue I have is that I want it to work between activities and if I kill the first activity when the timer has not elapsed, will it still fire the intent once elapsed?
This leads me back to background service, as I want it the be persistent between activities, but killed when the app it killed/exited/closed.